# Cookie seems to travel cross browsers

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iis, cookies

So i'm getting some strange results when trying to set cookies.

I need to set a cookie so I can do some processing in php.

Here is the code to set a cookie(located in the header):

```
    /*
*   Check webp support
*/
Modernizr.on('webp', function (result) {
  if (result) {
    deleteCookie('webpsupport');
    setCookie("webpsupport", "yes", "365");
    console.log("webp support");
  }
  else {
    deleteCookie('webpsupport');
    console.log("webp no support");
  }
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

var deleteCookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

Noew the PHP code im using:

```
$patterns = array("/.jpg/", "/.jpeg/", "/.png/");
if (isset($_COOKIE['webpsupport']) && $_COOKIE['webpsupport'] == "yes") 
    $thePostThumbUrl = preg_replace($patterns, "_result.webp", $thePostThumbUrl);
```

So the problem is if I load chrome first it display .webp image.
console message is `webp support`

Now if I load the site in edge the webp iamges are displayed.
console message is `webp no support`

Now for the wierd part.
If I reverse the process, so clear cache on website then load edge the original .jpg extensions are shown. But if I then load website in chrome the .jpg versions of the image are also shown.

This one has me baffled, seems straight forward enough.

Also in edge debugger I can confirm the cookie doesn't exist. So how can the PHP code run @.@

Anyone encountered anything like this.

> UPDATE If I use this code it echos out yes:
>       `if (isset($_COOKIE['webpsupport'])) echo $_COOKIE['webpsupport'];` Also changed the cookie name from
>   `webpsupport` to `webpsupported` just incase there was some kind of
>   caching issue. But it still the same.

Comment: Hmm from what I've read up about cookies it's impossible to have them transferred between browsers, yet it's happening somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found out what's going on.

I'm using the w3 total cache plugin, which creates a page cache. Now this seems to be storing the cookie so when I use another browser I'm getting the unexpected results.

Now w3 total cache has a setting to exclude pages from the cache(in page cache settings) if the cookie exists like so:

[image]

now the problem with this is that no page will be cached, which defeats the purpose of having the page cache.

but this was the problem for me and I hope it helps someone else.

Now to figure out a way around this problem :(